# Fill an empty column according to information from another column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to fill an empty column according to information from another column

**My dataframe**

```
   A        B                                    C
0  F    House                     Are you at home?
1  E    House    description: to deliver tomorrow
2  F    Apt                 Here is some exemples 
3  F    House          description: a brown table
4  E    Apt               description: in the bus
5  F    House                 Hello, how are you?
6  E    Apt                     description: keys
```

So, I create a D column and if column C starts with 'description', I fill in 'fuzzy', if not with 'buzzy'.

```
new_column['D'] = ''
```

And I try to fill them

```
def fill_column(delete_column):
    if new_column['D'].loc[new_column['D'].str.startswith('description:'):
        new_column['D'] == 'fuzzy'
    else:
        new_column['D'] == 'buzzy'

    return new_column
```

**My output:**

```
  File "<ipython-input-41-ec3c1407168c>", line 6
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Good output:**

```
   A        B                                   C       D
0  F    House                    Are you at home?   buzzy
1  E    House    description: to deliver tomorrow   fuzzy
2  F    Apt                 Here is some exemples   buzzy
3  F    House          description: a brown table   fuzzy
4  E    Apt               description: in the bus   fuzzy
5  F    House                 Hello, how are you?   buzzy
6  E    Apt                     description: keys   fuzzy
```

Comment: You are missing a closing ] in the line `if new_column['D'].loc[new_column['D'].str.startswith('description:'):`

Comment: Using np.where   with startswith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `if-else` statements here, you can do this cleanly in a single line using `np.where`:

```
df['D'] = np.where(
    df['C'].str.startswith('description:'), 'fuzzy', 'buzzy')
```

You can do this with a single `loc` call, since you're assigning two values only.

```
df['D'] = 'buzzy'
df.loc[df['C'].str.startswith('description:'), 'D'] = 'fuzzy'
```

Or use `df.mask`/`df.where` like @jpp suggested in the comments:

```
df['D'] = 'buzzy'
df['D'] = df['D'].mask(df['C'].str.startswith('description:'), 'fuzzy')
```

And lastly, using `map`:

```
m = {True: 'fuzzy', False: 'buzzy'}
df['D'] = df['C'].str.startswith('description:').map(m)
```

---

```
print(df)
   A      B                                 C      D
0  F  House                  Are you at home?  buzzy
1  E  House  description: to deliver tomorrow  fuzzy
2  F    Apt             Here is some exemples  buzzy
3  F  House        description: a brown table  fuzzy
4  E    Apt           description: in the bus  fuzzy
5  F  House               Hello, how are you?  buzzy
6  E    Apt                 description: keys  fuzzy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_column.loc[new_column['C'].str.startswith('description:'), 'D'] = 'fuzzy'
new_column.loc[~new_column['C'].str.startswith('description:'), 'D'] = 'buzzy'
```